# ASP.NET website times out before session timeout or execution timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, load-balancing, session-timeout

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 web app running in a load balanced cluster with 3 nodes. The website is expected to run continuously for more than a day without much user activity. The website keeps refreshing its contents for every 5 minutes.

The website is configured with high values for session timeout and execution timeout. The Application Pool has been configured not to recycle automatically. The session mode being used is SQLServer. We have also specified machine key in the web.config to avoid session errors.

However, we have been still noticing the session to timeout during night. The web server Event Viewer doesn't show any errors related to Application Pool recycle. When we get error in the website, the website redirects to the WSSO login page (on refreshing) indicating that session has timed out. WSSO timeout has been configured to 16 hours. And in this case, the website refreshes every 5 minutes.

Could anyone please advice what could be the cause for the timeout.

Thanks,
Arvind

Comment: When the site refreshes, does the load balancer make sure that the request goes back to the same node?  If not, do the nodes have the same machine code?

Comment: Yes, we have the same machine key for all the three nodes in the cluster. The session state is not being maintained on the web server. We are using SQLServer for session management.    <sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" mode="SQLServer" timeout="525600" sqlConnectionString="Server=SQL-XXX-50-1D\XXX04; Database=NW_dNET02; Integrated Security=true" />

Comment: `Pool has been configured not to recycle automatically` How did you do this exactly?

Comment: The default idle timeout for the App Pool has been removed to ensure that App Pool doesn't have a idle timeout.

Comment: When you say removed, did you set it to zero?  Or you just removed the value?  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2008/04/22/disable-recycling-in-iis-7-use-appcmd.aspx

Comment: The "Idle Time-out (minutes)" property was set to 0.

Comment: The Regular Time Interval property is set to zero for this Application Pool.